# Should SO have an archived answer system?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I read though some of my old answers and questions seeing if any needed updating and I noticed I have a lot of PHP questions that are using deprecated `mysql_` methods.

Should Stack overflow have an archive system where the question or answer can be marked for "archive" based on some criteria like "Deprecated code" so a notice could be shown for anyone reading that page, similar to the "close as a duplicate" system works.

For example, this question, although valid at the time, is no longer valid due to changes in the programming language used.

This could then also be something that is voted-upon/flagged like the duplicate system.

What do others think? Is this something that should exist?

Comment: I'm more looking for a discussion around a method as some of the answer it could be overused so is there a better way to implement it? and mine is it could be a flag or it could be just left to the OP or Answer's owner to mark it